# What is method to use foreach on a txt file?

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

Below embedded `foreach` commands needs `$user` to come from `list.txt`, dump groups from AD into `$user.txt` file and remove.

How do I specify `$user` as each line in the `list.txt` whild also verifying the formatting of the list inside the `list.txt` is just one name per line, no comma?

```
foreach ($user in .\list.txt) {
    $groups = (Get-ADUser $user -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf
    Add-Content -Path C:\TEMP\RemoveGroups\$user.txt -Value $groups
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        Remove-ADGroupMember $group -Member $user
    }
```

Comment: You have to get the content of your text file first with `Get-Content`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$List = Get-Content .\List.txt
Foreach ($User in $List){
    $Groups = (Get-ADUser $user -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf

    Foreach ($GroupDN in $Groups){
        Try {
            $Group = Get-ADGroup $GroupDN
            Remove-ADGroupMember $Group -member $user -ErrorAction Stop
            $Succeed = $Succeed,$Group.Name -join ";"
        }
        Catch {
            $Failed = $Failed,$Group.Name -Join ";"
        }
    }

    $temp = New-Object psobject -ArgumentList @{
        User    = $User
        Succeed = $Succeed
        Failed  = $Failed
    }

    Export-Csv -InputObject $temp -Path C:\TEMP\RemoveGroups\Result.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

You will get the CSV file like this:

**User,Succeed,Failed**

**user1,Group1;Group2,Group3;Group4**

**user2,Group2;Group3,Group1;Group4**

Comment: I had to replace -ArgumentList with -Property for the tables to populate usable data. However, this is the results i receive: https://i.imgur.com/bS9AwV7.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code.

```
# Read the list of users to an array of strings.
$users = Get-Content .\list.txt
foreach ($user in $users) {
    # Validate that the username only contains a-z and 0-9.
    if ($user -match "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$") {
        $groups = (Get-ADUser $user -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf
        Add-Content -Path C:\TEMP\RemoveGroups\$user.txt -Value $groups
        foreach ($group in $groups) {
            Remove-ADGroupMember $group -member $user
        }
    }
}
```